# Kendo-prompt: Can you change the kendo prompt popup to display a text area instead of a <input>

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to create a kendo prompt dialog box, that can take a large text with 200 characters.

The kendo prompt's are predefined with an `<input>` box. How can I change it from input to textarea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can but you have to hack it a bit.

I wanted to use a Kendo Prompt box to enter a generic "comments" field and the stock text input wasn't optimal due to the size of my comments field, 250 bytes.

Here's how I did it.

In my JavaScript file I defined the prompt as such:

```html
function editComments(comments) {
 return $("<div></div>").kendoPrompt({
  title: 'Image Comments',
  value: comments,
  content: "<textarea class='k-textbox editComments' maxlength='250'>" + comments + "</textarea>",
 }).data("kendoPrompt").open().result;
}
```

Then when a user presses my comments button, I execute the widget like so:

```
if (buttonActionType === 'Comments') {
    var comments = clickedItem[0].children[1].innerText;
    window.editComments(comments).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }, function () {
        alert("Cancel entering value.");
    });
}
```

You will need to hide the regular text input element that this widget defaults to, otherwise you'll see the textarea input above a text input.

In CSS:

```
.k-prompt-container .k-textbox {
     display: none;
 }
```

Comment: I highly suggest not to go this way! Yes, it works. For how long? One release, three releases? Sooner or later, they will change something in Kendo and you have to find out how to adjust your hackish code to make it work again. At the very beginning, I had plenty of workarounds and hackish code in my applications before was tired of all the broken things and decided to stick what is offered by Kendo and avoid these kind of "solutions".

Comment: Actually, I completely agree with you. The best approach would be just to use a Kendo window and build your form within using a textarea input and your own kendo buttons for submit and cancel. After I used the above method, I actually did decide to not use Kendo Prompt widget and to instead use a Kendo Window. If someone does decide to use this hack, at least they know they can, with caveats.

Comment: The solution saved me a lot of effort

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Here is an example with a treeview instead of the normal text input

```
https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dialog/treeview-integration.
```

In this example the property **content:** does the trick.

Comment: No need to downvote my answer. It was asked for a Kendo prompt. And that one does not support custom content. Read first, vote afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

You can't. You have to create your own dialog and provide the textarea by yourself. The shortcut `kendo.prompt()` is meant to be as simple as possible, there is no room for customizations.

Besides: It is perfectly possible to enter more than 200 characters. It's not very nice in an input but possible.

Comment: customizing it would have made my work a lot more simple :) but not complaining! Thanks!

Comment: Where there's a will, there's a way! Take a look at my answer above.